# Calculate or approximate $\sum\limits_{k=801}^{849}{ \binom {2400} {k}} $

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

Is there any formula which can help me  to calculate directly the following sum :

$$\sum_{k=801}^{849} \binom {2400} {k} \text{ ? } $$

Or can you help me for an approximation?

Comment: I suspect you can only get a decent approximation without a brute force calculation.

Comment: I'm the only one who's up-voted this so far after two others have posted answers.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : Do you really only _suspect_ that??

Comment: @MichaelHardy There might be some trick for these particular values that I didn't notice :)

Comment: OK, actually it's a fair number of SDs away from the mean, so it's unclear how well the CLT will work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$
\sum_{k=801}^{\color{red}{849}}{ \binom {\color{blue}{2400}} {k}} \approx\binom {\color{blue}{2400}} {\color{red}{849}}\cdot\frac1{1-\frac{\color{red}{849}}{\color{blue}{2400}-\color{red}{849}}}=\binom {2400} {849}\cdot\frac{1551}{702}
$$
[The RHS](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binomial%282400%2C849%291551%2F702) is approximately $6.323\cdot10^{675}$. [The LHS](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/362686) is approximately $6.302\cdot10^{675}$. The relative error is less than $0.5\%$.

Comment: from where do you know this approximation ?

Comment: Compare ${2400\choose k}$ to ${2400\choose k-1}$, the ratio is $k/(2401-k)\approx849/(2400-849)$ when $k\leqslant849$, $k$ close to $849$. Hence the main contribution to the sum comes from the last terms, which behave roughly like $a^ix$ for $x$ the last term, $a\lt1$ the ratio and $i\geqslant0$. And the sum over every $i\geqslant0$ of $a^ix$ is $x/(1-a)$.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binomial%282400%2C849%291551%2F702) shows this is within $\frac 12\%$ of the exact answer

Answer (score 5):

This can be computed using `Sum([801..849],k->Binomial(2400,k));` in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/), which gives:

> 6301658589252789789015394548565753645266501707773027193237154277135560724763449264321985233013302083482867404033075780563717296980953719800345900949177485867102506636266227692550924263009975743334850017707243878849834456104549363646796461925922393903588452037583051589363088432111720742572219650413596433425388801991237454447814199442671137445437352797716466882851664850702263146918207481280464655954611009667731242187491732271534642120317745100700127873871822642415935966102219060535417049206248240674733546894430281964131727432744187261341581666985170681694633765243107624160397671919189350311078072089739085127819403410647241830980073127572833414340863527184811939282852420

This is approximately $6.30 \times 10^{675}$.

Comment: Already the last term ${2400\choose 849}$ is $\approx10^{675}$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction!  I used Wolfram|Alpha for that, and must have missed the "input too long" warning.

Comment: The new value is more plausible... (But did you use W|A or GAP?)

Comment: I used GAP to compute the base-10 log, which gets rounded down.  Since the number isn't a power of 10, it gives the number of digits.